# In WPF Only icon of a button is click able not whole of the button

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I am trying to make a costume button in c# wpf. I used material design themes for inserting an icon inside the button but when I run the program, only the icon inside the button is click able not the whole button. what should I do to fix this?

I did this for button style:

```
<Application.Resources>

           <Style x:Key="MyButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
           <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
           <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
           <Setter Property="Template">
               <Setter.Value>
                   <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                       <Border Name="border" BorderThickness="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                           <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

                       </Border>
                       <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                           <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" >
                               <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.8"  />

                           </Trigger>
                       </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                   </ControlTemplate>
               </Setter.Value>
           </Setter>
       </Style>

   </Application.Resources>
```

here is the button:

```
 <Button x:Name="btnClose" Style="{StaticResource MyButton}"  Width="30" Height="30" Padding="0" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="Gray" Margin="10 0" Click="btnClose_Click">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Power" Height="30" Width="30"></materialDesign:PackIcon>
                    </Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `Background` property to a `Brush` like for example `Transparent` instead of setting it to `{x:Null}`:

```
<Button x:Name="btnClose" Style="{StaticResource MyButton}"  Width="30" Height="30" Padding="0" 
        Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="Gray" Margin="10 0" Click="btnClose_Click">
    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Power" Height="30" Width="30"></materialDesign:PackIcon>
</Button>
```

Comment: I changed materialDesign:PackIcon to "Transparent" and it is working. Thank u so much